# PHP - Globalize namespace contents

Tags: php, namespaces, package

I can't find information related to it, the thing is that I have a namespace like this:

```
// foo.php

namespace foo;

function blah()
{

}
```

And then I include it / use it

```
require_once 'foo.php';

foo\blah();
```

Now I want to do the same but without specifying 'foo' all the time (something like using namespace in C++), is that possible?

```
require_once 'foo.php'

// using namespace foo;

blah(); // ?
```

Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the required file is in the same folder level with the file calling it? You can make some checks by throwing a simple if statement to verify.

```
$file_fnc = '/path/to/foo/file';

if(file_exists($file_fnc)) {
    require_once $file_fnc;
} else { 
    echo "File not found"; 
}
```

This will help you determine if your file is truly existing. If it exists then we continue debugging from there. Test it and reply

Comment: Before nothing thank's for answering, my problem is not the file, my code works perfectly and I can import the file correctly, the thing is that I want to bind the namespace's functions to the current file where I include it, so I can do like a Java import e.g (import javax.swing.JFrame) instead of writting the whole node or like in C++ where you could use a namespace like (using namespace std) and instead of use the std :: reference you call the function directly. I want to do exactly the same but on php (it seems I can't).

Comment: I haven't implemented such except using Namespaces. You can also try Google to see if such exists for PHP.